# How delete/add elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
          [0]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(11) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950) 
          }
          [1]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(8) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950)  
          } 
          [2]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(8) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950)  
          }
          [3]=> array(3) { 
               [0]=> string(8) "art_7883" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(4335)  
          }
}
```

In the global array I would like to find an array with element (ex. element `art_7880`) and then I would like to add in a global array one array with an element `art_7880`.

For ex.:
find element, ex. art_7880

In the global array, the element would be an array with `art_7880` - `[0]=> string(8) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950)`

I need to get this array `[0]=> string(8) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950)` and add or remove to the global array once.

This is the code I used:

```
foreach ($all_array as $keys => $elms) {
if(in_array('art_7880', $elms) && !in_array('art_7880', $arr_uniq)){
$arr_uniq[] = ''art_7880'';
var_dump($elms); //should been show `[0]=> string(11) "art_7880" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(2950)`
}
```

But It doesn't work...

Can somebody please tell me where the error is?

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you have any sample code to examine?

Comment: Why do you two quotes arround `$arr_uniq[] = ''art_7880'';`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think the problem is that you have two sets of quotes around "art_7880", which end up giving you an error like "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'art_7880' (T_STRING)...". The following code should then provide the correct output:

```
foreach ($all_array as $keys => $elms) {
    if(in_array('art_7880', $elms) && !in_array('art_7880', $arr_uniq)){
        $arr_uniq[] = 'art_7880';
        var_dump($elms);
    }
}
```

Unless your issue is (possibly also) that you've got a 3D array here, but you're only treating it as a 2D one. (Because I noticed you've got a lot of nested array there.) In which case, this should give the correct output:

```
foreach ($all_array[0] as $keys => $elms) {
    if(in_array('art_7880', $elms) && !in_array('art_7880', $arr_uniq)){
        $arr_uniq[] = 'art_7880';
        var_dump($elms);
    }
}
```

Hope one of these code snippets were helpful. Good luck!